# Error in Content Based Routing for Web Services

Tags: mule

I want to implement content-based-routing for SOAP messages. I get thie error " 
Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xac (at char #1, byte #-1)". Web service is in Axis2

My mule-config.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:pattern="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern"
      xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
      xmlns:mule-xml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml"      
      xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.4/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/pattern/3.1/mule-pattern.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/3.4/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/3.4/mule-xml.xsd">

  <mule-xml:namespace-manager>
    <mule-xml:namespace prefix="ns1" uri="http://www.example.org/hello1"/>
    <mule-xml:namespace prefix="ns2" uri="http://www.example.org/hello2"/>
  </mule-xml:namespace-manager>

  <flow name="XPathExample">

    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8086/services" />

    <choice>

      <when evaluator="xpath" expression="//*/namespace::*[name()='ns1'] = 'http://www.example.org/hello1'">
        <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/hello1" />
      </when>           

      <when evaluator="xpath" expression="//*/namespace::*[name()='ns2'] = 'http://www.example.org/hello2'">
        <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/hello2" />
      </when>        

    </choice>

  </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: If you point the client you use to send requests to http://localhost:8086/services on http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/hello1, do you also have the error? Trying to see if it's a Mule induced issue. Also is there a mix of OSes, more specifically is there some Windows involved?

Comment: Hi, I solved this by adding contentType="application/soap+xml" and encoding="UTF-8" to outbound-endpoint and inbound-endpoint. This was developed and run in Ubuntu